# How to do single auth for multiple projects in laravel?

Tags: laravel, authentication

I have 2 projects under development: blog and shop. These projects will be stored on different servers, but authentication must be the same for all these projects and it should be on server side (with sessions and csrf, not js api calls for authentication with jwt token or smth else). Auth endpoints will be in the shop project. For shop project it will be easy to make an default laravel auth, but how to share it to the blog project?

I guess I need to make an middleware which will send an request to the shop server with client cookies, but I'm stuck in this problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You should create a different app, an oauth2 server, which authenticates the users for both sites.

Comment: Yes, I understand that I am moving to microservices. I don't understand how to authorize users on laravel side using oauth2 server? Should it be the httpOnly cookie with auth token and when user send a request to the blog server, blog server will send a request to the oauth server with this cookie?

Comment: There is a very good article with the details on how to implement this: https://blog.pusher.com/make-an-oauth2-server-using-laravel-passport/